# Website load slow on first run in IIS7 integrated pipiline mode

Tags: iis-7, web, render, integrated

I have a pure html website, there is nothing to render.
On first run it takes about 10 seconds to load.
In the second time and above in a scope of 10-15 minutes it takes less then a second to load, Even if I open another browser.

I can see that a browser waiting for a response from the server, the server is IIS7  in integrated pipiline mode, if I set it to classic mode the issue is disappeared even if I will access again the website after 10 hours.

I'm pretty sure it's not about the application idle timeout because in integrated pipiline it's set to 1 hour.

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would probably be to add the Application Initialization plugin to your site. [This blogpost should be of help](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/implementing-application-initialization-on-iis-7-5/). Basically it just pings your website occasionally so it gets the long load time, rather than a user.